# Как получить user_id человека и записать его в БД MySQL? Aiogram, Pyton, Telegram

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Как можно реализовать эту функцию? При первом включении бота и при использовании команды /start (в первый раз) получать id человека и заносить сразу же в Базу Данных? У меня реализована загрузка файлов на БД через телеграм бота (с помощью скрипта).

Пример загрузки медиа:

```
import os
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from db_map import Base, MediaIds
from config import TOKEN, MY_ID, DB_FILENAME

logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s [ LINE:%(lineno)+3s ]#%(levelname)+8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)

engine = create_engine(f'sqlite:///{DB_FILENAME}')

if not os.path.isfile(f'./{DB_FILENAME}'):
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)


BASE_MEDIA_PATH = './demo-media'


async def uploadMediaFiles(folder, method, file_attr):
    folder_path = os.path.join(BASE_MEDIA_PATH, folder)
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.startswith('.'):
            continue

        logging.info(f'Started processing {filename}')
        with open(os.path.join(folder_path, filename), 'rb') as file:
            msg = await method(MY_ID, file, disable_notification=True)
            if file_attr == 'photo':
                file_id = msg.photo[-1].file_id
            else:
                file_id = getattr(msg, file_attr).file_id
            session = Session()
            newItem = MediaIds(file_id=file_id, filename=filename)
            try:
                session.add(newItem)
                session.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(
                    'Couldn\'t upload {}. Error is {}'.format(filename, e))
            else:
                logging.info(
                    f'Successfully uploaded and saved to DB file {filename} with id {file_id}')
            finally:
                session.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [
    loop.create_task(uploadMediaFiles('pics', bot.send_photo, 'photo')),
    loop.create_task(uploadMediaFiles('videos', bot.send_video, 'video')),
    loop.create_task(uploadMediaFiles('videoNotes', bot.send_video_note, 'video_note')),
    loop.create_task(uploadMediaFiles('files', bot.send_document, 'document')),
    loop.create_task(uploadMediaFiles('ogg', bot.send_voice, 'voice')),
        ]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)

loop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
loop.close()
Session.remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос "*При первом включении бота и при использовании команды /start (в первый раз) получать id человека и заносить сразу же в Базу Данных?*"

Написал одной функцией, но на логику разбить, думаю, не составить труда.
p.s. не проверял.

```
import os
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection

bot = Bot(token=os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start", "help"])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    """Help message for starting"""
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    
    data_query = (user_id)
    # проверка на существование юзера в бд
    query = ("select if( exists(select* from users where user_id=%s), 1, 0)")
    
    conn = MySQLConnection(**config)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, data_query)
    cursor.close()
    
    user_exist= cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if user_exist:
         query = ("insert into users (user_id) values (%s)")
         data_query = (user_id)
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         cursor.execute(query, data_query)
         conn.commit()
         cursor.close()
         conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```